# How to set 2FA for Windows Remote Desktop login

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

How can I configure Windows on my laptop to require 2FA (preferably via authenticate) when connecting via Remote Desktop.

I have a workgroup login. So not a domain login. And not a Microsoft login. (Yes, very old school.)

Comment: @Peregrino69 Unfortunately no - that's for an AD login. I have a workgroup login.

Comment: Dang. All the options for standalone PCs seem to be commercial and rely on 3rd party authentication services. Nothing for RDP, RealVNC can be enabled for 2FA with [Authy](https://authy.com/guides/realvnc/) - the Android app is free. Maybe that'll help. FreeRADIUS with Google Authenticator PAM might be a workable solution too; [this instruction](https://networkjutsu.com/freeradius-google-authenticator/) is for Linux but it's also available also for Windows.